# How can I set How can I set the color for geom_line without getting the error “Discrete value supplied to continuous scale”

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2

I use the follow code to create Storage utilization chart and trend.  My issue is I cannot get geom_line to be any color but either black or the variegated steel blue color.  If I attempt to set the color in the line with `color="purple"` I receive

> Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

I am fairly new to R coding and so I have researched the error and many of the solutions seem to be centered around coding errors or the data being the wrong class type.  The data for the Y values are all numeric and the X values are Date values.

My preference is to set a solid color for the lines but different variegated colors for each line could also work.

I also included snipits from my data frames.

```
data  
         Time     FC FCFree     NL NLFree  SSD SSDFree  
1  2014-05-05 179886  64722 104628 126412 6576    5264  
2  2014-05-12 180486  64122 104628 126412 6576    5264  
3  2014-05-19 182286  62322 104628 126412 6576    5264  
4  2014-05-26 184686  59922 104628 126412 6748    5092  
5  2014-06-02 185282  59326 104620 126420 6748    5092  

df80  
         date     X.Lo.80  X.Hi.80  
1  2016-02-12 152669.3677 191089.0  
2  2016-02-19 143284.9057 197909.7  
3  2016-02-26 135687.2835 202943.7  
4  2016-03-04 128999.3090 207068.0  
5  2016-03-11 122883.3810 210620.2  

df95  
         date       Lo.95    Hi.95  
1  2016-02-12 159318.5530 184439.8  
2  2016-02-19 152738.6943 188456.0  
3  2016-02-26 147327.1874 191303.8  
4  2016-03-04 142510.4670 193556.8  
5  2016-03-11 138067.7879 195435.8  

Allocat  
         Time Allocated  
1  2014-05-05    291090  
2  2014-05-12    291690  
3  2014-05-19    293490  
4  2014-05-26    296062  
5  2014-06-02    296650  

Subscribe
         date SubScribe  
1  2014-05-05  492839.0  
2  2014-05-12  486848.3  
3  2014-05-19  490117.7  
4  2014-05-26  494348.3  
5  2014-06-02  498552.3  

dfmedian
         date MedianTrend  
1  2016-02-12    171879.2  
2  2016-02-19    172480.7  
3  2016-02-26    173082.2  
4  2016-03-04    173683.7  
5  2016-03-11    174285.2  

dftrnd  
         date    Trend  
1  2016-02-12 171879.2  
2  2016-02-19 170597.3  
3  2016-02-26 169315.5  
4  2016-03-04 168033.7  
5  2016-03-11 166751.8  

TotalCap  
487488
```

Plotting Code

```
ggplot() +  geom_area(data=mdata, position="stack", aes(x=Time,y=value,group=variable,fill=variable))+  
    geom_ribbon(data=df80, aes(x=date,ymin=X.Lo.80,ymax=X.Hi.80,fill="Accuracy80"))+  
    geom_ribbon(data=df95, aes(x=date,ymin=Lo.95,ymax=Hi.95,fill="Accuracy95"))+  
    geom_line(data=Subscribe, aes(x=date,y=SubScribe,fill="Subscription"))+  
    geom_line(data=Allocat, aes(x=Time,y=Allocated,fill="AllocationLine"))+  
    geom_line(data=dfmedian, aes(x=date,y=MedianTrend,fill="MedianTrend"))+  
    geom_line(data=dftrnd, aes(x=date,y=Trend,colour=Trend))+  
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept=TotalCap), colour="#990000", linetype="dashed")+  
    xlab("Date")+  
    ylab("GiB") +  
    ggtitle(PlotTitle)+  
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("Accuracy80"="gray80",  
      "Accuracy95"="lightsteelblue3",  
      "Allocated"="forestgreen",  
      "Free"="springgreen2",  
      "Trend"="steelblue4",  
      "Subscription"="black",  
      "AllocationLine"="purple",  
      "MedianTrend"="coral4",  
      "FC"="#93AA00",  
      "FCFree"="#00BA38",  
      "NL"="#00C19F",  
      "NLFree"="greenyellow",  
      "SSD"="#619CFF",  
      "SSDFree"="violet"))+  
    scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)+  
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))+  
    guides(variable = guide_legend(order=1), Trend = guide_legend(order=2))+  
    scale_colour_continuous(labels=comma)
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to make you example a more simplified version that reproduces the error.  This would include a small subset of data (you can use `dput` and paste the results).  This will help you get an answer more quickly.

Comment: You are attempting to map both continuous (`Trend`) and discrete (`"purple"`) variables to your colour scale.  You can resolve this multiple ways: 1) use only one type of scale for all lines with `scale_fill_(continuous or discrete)`, 2) map the colours outside of `aes()` (as you have done already with `geom_hline`).

Comment: Oshun  The second choice was exactly what I was wanting.  I have now set the color outside of aes().    I did not realize that the color could be set outside of the aes() block.

Comment: @Oshun per your suggestion I changed where the colour was set. <br/  `code`  geom_line(data=Subscribe, aes(x=date,y=SubScribe,fill="Subscription"), colour="black")+
    geom_line(data=Allocat, aes(x=Time,y=Allocated,fill="AllocationLine"), colour="purple")+
 geom_line(data=dfmedian, aes(x=date,y=MedianTrend,fill="MedianTrend"), colour="coral4")+